# how to pass variables as parameters salesforce cli - sfdx force:apex:execute

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

How to pass a powershell variable as parameter to apex execute

```
$paramstring = 'long json string from a local file';
sfdx force:apex:execute
apexclass ac = new apexclass($paramstring);
ac.mainmethod();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sfdx force:apex:execute` has [two modes of operation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_apex.htm#cli_reference_execute). You can either provide it with a file via `-f`:

```
sfdx force:apex:execute -f myApexScript.apex
```

or you can run in a quasi-interactive or piped mode with

```
sfdx force:apex:execute
```

In the latter case, you can either enter your script at the prompt, interactively, or you can pipe a script into standard input. In a Bash script, for example (I'm not sure what the PowerShell equivalent might be), you'd do

```
cat somescript.apex | sfdx force:apex:execute
```

or

```
echo "System.debug('Test');" | sfdx force:apex:execute
```

You can apply any of those paradigms using the appropriate PowerShell idioms. SFDX doesn't have any special parameter-passing syntax; you just have to construct a text script and supply it to the command.